# how to write test cases for spring security

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, spring-security

i am new to spring and spring security but i was asked to develop test case for Spring security,

Could any one guide me how to?

Best Regards

Comment: Please do not vote to close this question, i am sure that this will help many and not only me.

Comment: May be but could you explain more on your comment like support your comment with example

Comment: is this correct place to learn : http://learningmonk.wordpress.com/2009/03/14/how-to-write-testcase-for-spring-security-defined-by-annotations/

Comment: Sorry - please clarify. Do you need to create tests for your application (and your application uses Spring and SpringSecurity)? Or you create the additional module for SpringSecurity (I understand your question in this way from the subject)?

Comment: it is additional module for SpringSecurity. but not sure which is the best way to do it:(

Comment: Yes, it is helpful information, but according to the StackOverflow rules you are supposed to ask *specific* programming questions, and this is a general question about testing security in spring. If you altered your question to give more specifics (eg what aspect of security are you testing?) that would help... Also it's good form to add: what you've tried yourself, the research you've done (even just googling) and what you tried from that... which bits exactly you got stuck on. It's the lack of *all* these things that's why people are voting to close.

Comment: I don't see the reason for closing this question is justified there is answer for this question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Security developed with high coverage of test cases. Please look on the existing test cases.
For example, if you create your own provider please look the example here:
https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/~tag=3.0.8.RELEASE/spring-security/core/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao

If you create your own authentication filter please look the example here:
https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/~tag=3.0.8.RELEASE/spring-security/web/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www

Hope it helps. Please tell me if you need any additional clarifications.

Best regards,

Michael

Comment: Thanks Michael I will look in to these and revert you if i need any clarifications.